# How to find connected Device ID through iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, iphone

I'd like to use iTunes to get information from an iPhone 7+. I'm a developer playing around with iOS development for the first time, and am trying to deploy a toy/hobby iOS app (that I wrote via XCode) to my iPhone.

It looks like the first thing I need to do is figure out what my iPhone's Device ID is. Following the instructions for [finding Device ID through iTunes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW46), I launched iTunes and then connected my phone to it. However, whereas (according to that link) I *should* be seeing a screen that looks like this:

[image]

I only see a screen that contains three fields:

- Capacity
- Phone Number
- Serial Number

But I don't see a Device ID or **UDID** field like the document says. Do iPhone's not have UDIDs? Is the Serial Number a useable substitute for UDID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on your phone in the top-left corner to show phone details.

[image]

From here, you can choose Summary in the sidebar, then click on your serial to show the UDID.

Comment: Thanks @grgarside (+1) - your suggestion worked but I still cannot find my "Device ID" or "UDID" as the linked document portrays. I updated my question with the latest problem, any ideas how to locate this UDID?

Comment: @smeeb Have you followed the last sentence of my answer per ‘click on your serial to show the UDID’?

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to click on the device icon next to the Category chooser.
2. Click on the serial number itself to change it to UDID.

[image: iTunes]

Comment: Thanks @pjc90 (+1) - your suggestion worked but I still cannot find my "Device ID" or "UDID" as the linked document portrays. I updated my question with the latest problem, any ideas how to locate this UDID?

Comment: @smeeb see my edit